# Multiple Condition on collection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a huge collection of Data in Mongo's collection where some user behavioural events from my application are stored with `event name`, `user id` and `time`.

I am stuck in a case where I want to get list of all users who perform `Event A` within specific time but did not perform `Event B` within same time.

**For Example**, Within last 1 hour, i want to see how many users perform `AddToCart` but didn't perform `OrderPlace` event. (May be user placed an order within first 15 minutes of same hour but again added new products to cart, i want them too).

Is there any simple way to achieve this in single `Aggregation` using `$facet` or `$group` stages. Or if `find` could work?

**Sample Code**

```
db.Collection.insertMany([
  {
    _id: 27,
    eventName: "View",
    user: "alpha4",
    time: 1615188155000
  },
  {
    _id: 26,
    eventName: "orderPlace",
    user: "alpha4",
    time: 1615188145000
  },
  {
    _id: 25,
    eventName: "addToCart",
    user: "alpha4",
    time: 1615188135000
  },
  {
    _id: 28,
    eventName: "Info",
    user: "alpha1",
    time: 1615188125000
  },
  {
    _id: 24,
    eventName: "addToCart",
    user: "alpha1",
    time: 1615188115000
  },
  {
    _id: 23,
    eventName: "View",
    user: "alpha1",
    time: 1615188105000
  },
  {
    _id: 22,
    eventName: "category",
    user: "alpha1",
    time: 1615188095000
  },
  {
    _id: 21,
    eventName: "addToCart",
    user: "alpha1",
    time: 1615188085000
  },
  {
    _id: 20,
    eventName: "addToCart",
    user: "alpha1",
    time: 1615188075000
  },
  {
    _id: 19,
    eventName: "category",
    user: "alpha1",
    time: 1615188065000
  },
  {
    _id: 18,
    eventName: "addToCart",
    user: "alpha3",
    time: 1615188055000
  },
  {
    _id: 17,
    eventName: "View",
    user: "alpha3",
    time: 1615188045000
  },
  {
    _id: 16,
    eventName: "category",
    user: "alpha3",
    time: 1615188035000
  },
  {
    _id: 15,
    eventName: "addToCart",
    user: "alpha3",
    time: 1615188025000
  },
  {
    _id: 14,
    eventName: "addToCart",
    user: "alpha1",
    time: 1615188015000
  },
  {
    _id: 13,
    eventName: "category",
    user: "alpha1",
    time: 1615188005000
  },
  {
    _id: 12,
    eventName: "addToCart",
    user: "alpha1",
    time: 1615187995000
  },
  {
    _id: 11,
    eventName: "View",
    user: "alpha1",
    time: 1615187985000
  },
  {
    _id: 10,
    eventName: "category",
    user: "alpha1",
    time: 1615187975000
  },
  {
    _id: 9,
    eventName: "orderPlace",
    user: "alpha1",
    time: 1615187965000
  },
  {
    _id: 8,
    eventName: "addToCart",
    user: "alpha1",
    time: 1615188155000
  },
  {
    _id: 7,
    eventName: "category",
    user: "alpha1",
    time: 1615187955000
  },
  {
    _id: 6,
    eventName: "addToCart",
    user: "alpha2",
    time: 1615187945000
  },
  {
    _id: 5,
    eventName: "View",
    user: "alpha2",
    time: 1615187935000
  },
  {
    _id: 4,
    eventName: "category",
    user: "alpha2",
    time: 1615187925000
  },
  {
    _id: 3,
    eventName: "addToCart",
    user: "alpha2",
    time: 1615187915000
  },
  {
    _id: 2,
    eventName: "addToCart",
    user: "alpha2",
    time: 1615187905000
  },
  {
    _id: 1,
    eventName: "category",
    user: "alpha2",
    time: 1615187895000
  },
  
]);
```

**Expected Result**

i should get `alpha1` , `alpha2`, `alpha3` bcz they all `addToCart` but didn't placed order. `Alpha1` placed order but after that again he added to cart in same hour. Aplha4 added to cart but also placed order ,so skip him.

```
//output
user => [alpha1, aplha2, alpha3]
```

Comment: it would be helpful if you add sample document or schema structure and expected result from that document.

Comment: @turivishal , please see question...i added sample...

Comment: please add your expected result format. we can't predict your expectation and use case of result.

Comment: @turivishal sir please check now... i edited again...

Comment: look at the [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/XxKNelE8mxp), i understand your question and expectation but can you confirm your expected json response format. there are many ways to result as per your expectation.

Comment: @turivishal Thanks a lot for playground... but there is onething missing... a check for `orderPlace ` event ... if user have added to cart  but after that placed order... do not return that user...

Comment: can you confirm now [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/5hMEWz9_rfc)

Comment: @turivishal , i got a very good idea from your help... in your latest playground... `orderPlace` event filter is still not working fine... `alpha1` placed order but again added products.... still it is in `not performed` ... i updated the Dataset in my question a bit ... please use that...

Comment: in simple words , we could say... if eventTime of `addToCart` is greater then eventTime of  most recent `orderPlace`, return the user.